# Isometry group of a compact manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Is an isometry group of a compact manifold always a compact group?

Comment: yes, this is true. Compare http://faculty.tcu.edu/richardson/Seminars/LieGroups.pdf prop. 3.13.

Comment: If you use topology of uniform convergence on the group of isometries, then this is immediate from Arzela-Ascoli's theorem. How do you topologize the isometry group?

Comment: @studiosus being a physics student I am afraid I know little about topology. I just have a compact manifold endowed with a riemannian signature metric (which is not specified). It is for studying compactfication in Kaluza Klein theories, if this tells you something.

Comment: @studiosus topology has long been in my to do list, but a man has to pass his courses and time cannot be stopped... nonetheless I'll have a look on that book!

Comment: @wspin : your reference only contains the statement without proof. There is a very readable article of Myers and Steenrod (The group of isometries of a Riemannian manifold. Ann. of Math. (2) 40 (1939), no. 2, 400–416) I can recommend. They show, more generally, that the group of isometries of a riemannian manifold is a Lie group, and observe that it is compact if the manifold is so.